CSS Grid BentoBox UI Column width issue on specific break-point
I have created a BentoBox UI using CSS grid, and it is working fine for the most part the only issue I'm facing is in between the break-point from 768px to 926px.
I'm using grid-template-columns to dynamically add in columns when enough space is available but between the above mentioned break-points I get a weird 2 columns layout where the first column is bigger than the minimum size I have defined in my CSS (400px) and the second column is really small.
Is there a proper way of fixing this or should I just increase the mobile media query range to also include this break-point
The tutorial I followed to implement this layout:
YouTube
My current code:
CodePen
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 50px;
}
.grid-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 400px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.grid-item {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid red;
    grid-row: span 1;
    grid-column: span 1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid-item-1x2 {
        grid-column: span 2;
    }
    .grid-item-2x1 {
        grid-row: span 2;
    }
    .grid-item-2x2 {
        grid-row: span 2;
        grid-column: span 2;
    }
}

Screenshot

Tried changing the values for the minmax function
Used different properties for column definition like grid-template-columns
Tried asking ChatGPT

